# Homogenize tag hover behavior

Tags: feature-request, tags, ignored-tags, tag-watching, tooltips

Currently, when I hover over a tag in a question on the main question page, a popup comes up describing the tag, the number of followers, letting me subscribe to the tag, favorite / unfavorite / etc.  However, when I hover over a tag in my "Favorite Tags" section, it simply shows a tooltip of "show questions tagged '%tagname%'".  The hover behaviour of the tags in the Favorite Tags (and Ignored Tags as well) should be the same as the tags on the questions; i.e., hovering over a tag on my Favorite Tags should show the same popup with # of followers, edit link, description, ability to subscribe, etc.  The current behaviour is divergent and a little confusing; particularly because the click behaviour on the tags is exactly the same; i.e., they take you to the list of questions tagged with that tag.

Comment: I am assuming that the SE crew did this for the favorite tags because 1) it reduces some of the heavy lifting required to render the main page and 2) since you favorited the tag yourself, you should already know what the tag means.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: To me, it appears that favorite tags are using a legacy system and that they haven't been migrated to the updated tag popup system, but I could be wrong.  I can safely say, though, that even for tags I've favorited, I'd like to see the things that are available on the other popup rather than the "show questions" bit.

Comment: Same deal for ignored tags. I guess consistency is nice for its intrinsic value, but to be honest, I've never wanted this.

Comment: Related/ possible duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104965/description-of-favorite-and-ignored-tags