# Description of favorite and ignored tags

Tags: feature-request, tags

When you hover a tag in the list of questions, you are presented with a description of the tag along with some other options.

**Why not include this feature when hovering your favorite and ignored tags as well?**

That way, it would be more consistent, also the current tooltip ("show questions tagged [foo](/questions/tagged/foo)") states the obvious and is kind of unnecessary. Moreover, the tooltip's text isn't even shown when hovering a tag in the list of questions although they both link to the same page.

Comment: Should you need detailed info on tags you explicitly decide to ignore or favour? How did you get to favour or ignore them in the first place, based on what knowledge? Second, consistency can lead to a christmas-tree of popups.